# HttpParty Proxy ip address usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, httparty, open-uri

So i have a call to an api, Looks like this (url removed for safety yada yada)

```
apicall = HTTParty.get(URI.encode('URL HERE'), headers: {"Authorization" => "Bearer apikey"}).parsed_response
```

Now what i'm wanting is to use my proxy ip address to access the web page. Would you be willing to point me in the right direction to do this?

I've aware how to do this in open-uri but not sure if its possibe to do a get request with a this gem.

Thanks
Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
apicall = HTTParty.get(
  'URL HERE',
  http_proxyaddr:'PROXY IP HERE',
  http_proxyport: 'PROXY PORT HERE',
  http_proxyuser: 'PROXY USERNAME HERE',
  http_proxypass: 'PROXY PASSWORD HERE',
  headers: {"Authorization" => "Bearer apikey"}
).parsed_response
```

Skip the `http_proxy****` keys that you don't have values for. Everything you need to better understand what you can implement in HTTParty can be found here: [HTTParty Github](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/master/lib/httparty.rb)